micrometer & spring boot: aws otlp opentelemtry to cloudwatch
It's not clear to me what dependency I really need.
Up to now, I've been creating only metrics and sending them to cloudwatch.
I've been using io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-cloudwatch2.
However, currently I need to also generate tracing and I need to use OpenTelemetry in order to take advantadge of autoinstrumentation.
So, should I add dependency io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-otlp or I should remove micrometer-registry-cloudwatch2 in place of micrometer-registry-otlp?
Cloudwatch accepts OTLP?


I need to also generate tracing and I need to use OpenTelemetry in order to take advantadge of autoinstrumentation.

The auto-instrumentation in Spring does not need OpenTelemetry, you can use OTel or Brave under the hood for tracing, it's your choice,

So, should I add dependency io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-otlp or I should remove micrometer-registry-cloudwatch2 in place of micrometer-registry-otlp?

You might want to look at Micrometer Tracing docs: https://docs.micrometer.io/tracing/reference/
Both micrometer-registry-cloudwatch2 and micrometer-registry-otlp are for metrics not tracing. If you want to use Micrometer Tracing you will need two things:

A tracer bridge (Brave or OTel)
A reporter/exporter for the tracer

For example:
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
implementation 'io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-brave'

or
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel'
implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp'

Check the docs, it discusses these details: https://docs.micrometer.io/tracing/reference/tracers.html

Cloudwatch accepts OTLP?

This can be a quick search with your favorite search engine. Based on my query, it seems not, it seems you should use X-Ray which is supported by both Brave and OTel but for OTel you need to deploy an extra component in your infra: the OTel Collector.
